# SMTP Connection for SendMail: Authentication Failure

Tags: authentication, vbscript, smtp, sendmail

I am facing a 'The server response was: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required' error despite providing authentication credentials. Given below is my SendMail.vbs

```html
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 

Dim ArgTo_s
Dim ArgSubject_s
Dim ArgMsgAttachFile_s
Dim ArgMsgBodyFile_s

ArgTo_s = ""
ArgSubject_s = ""
ArgMsgAttachFile_s = ""
ArgMsgBodyFile_s = ""

ArgTo_s = Wscript.Arguments(0)
ArgSubject_s = Wscript.Arguments(1)
ArgMsgBodyFile_s = Wscript.Arguments(2)

IF Wscript.Arguments.count > 3 then 
  ArgMsgAttachFile_s = Wscript.Arguments(3)
End If

SMTPServerName_s = "smtp.rediffmail.com"

' -- Open file and get message body -- Start --
Set MsgBody_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MsgBody_file = MsgBody_fso.OpenTextFile(ArgMsgBodyFile_s, ForReading)
MsgBody_s = MsgBody_file.ReadAll
MsgBody_file.Close
Set MsgBody_file = Nothing
Set MsgBody_fso = Nothing
' -- Open file and get message body -- End --

' -- Get the Hostname Start --
Set Shell_o = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
RegValue_s = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Hostname"
HostName_s = Shell_o.RegRead(RegValue_s)
' -- Get the Hostname End --

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = ArgSubject_s & " (Anonymous Application EMail)"
objMessage.From = UCase("test@myconsulting.co.in")
objMessage.To = ArgTo_s
objMessage.TextBody = MsgBody_s

If ArgMsgAttachFile_s <> "" Then
  objMessage.AddAttachment ArgMsgAttachFile_s
End If


objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "test@myconsulting.co.in"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "100000567"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.rediffmail.com"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send
```

Given below is the screen shot: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though you have added username and password, it seems that your script does not tell server to make authentication.

Try adding following code:

```
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
```

Comment: Thank you Hardik, but unfortunately, despite using the stated code I continue getting the error.

Comment: Okay.. Please run: "telnet smtp.rediffmail.com 25" from the system from which you are running your script and check if you are able to connect to this mail server.

Also, as you are using rediffmail.com mail server, make sure that you are using its correct username and password in your script

Comment: "telnet smtp.rediffmail.com 25" works fine and allows me to connect to the mail server.